# running php with Nginx server

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I am using apache server for php. So my doubt is can I use both Nginx and apache server for running on my system . Can be both server load on the systm? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to actually use both at the same time for a single app, for separate apps, or do you just want to try Nginx out?  Or something else altogether...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't see much benefit, but as long as they are listening to different ports, I don't see why not.

Here's a tutorial on how to setup php in nginx (just in case)

http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#PHP_via_FastCGI

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, for evaluation purposes, I would just fire up one of my Virtual Machines and run nginx in the test environment of your choice.

http://www.virtualbox.org/